# How can I avoid manually checking types in a list?

Tags: kotlin, type-erasure

I seem to recall reading that manually checking types in an object-oriented language (e.g., Kotlin)  usually means you are doing something "bad." I'm wondering if there is a better pattern for handling my situation than what I am currently doing ; currently I use `when` to check the type of the generic parameter, and then call the correct function based on type.

I have a set of data classes that store arrays of different types:

```
interface Data<T>
AData: Data<Int>
BData: Data<Double>
CData: Data<ComplexType>
DData: Data<Foo>
```

I can use these classes for doing various kinds of math, and *sometimes* I want to display them in a table. In order to do that (using JavaFX) I need to create a `TableColumn<Int, *>`, but I want to create a differently styled table column type based on type contained in the Data class.

I could think of two solutions. What I currently do is:

```
fun makeCol(data: Data<*>): TableColumn<Int, *> {
    return when {
        data[0] is Int -> makeBasicCol(data)
        data[0] is Double-> makeBasicCol(data)
        data[0] is ComplexType -> makeComplexCol(data)
        data[0] is Int -> makeFooCol(data)
    }
}
```

The other option I considered was creating a subclass of Data, something like `FxData`, which would have a function like `fun <TableColumn<Int, *>> provideFxCol()`. The problem I see with that is that now I am mixing UI functionality with the math functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it bad, it's actually a pretty common idiom in Java/Kotlin. In C++ it's something else, I believe that checking the type at runtime is generally frowned upon, because it incurs a significant performance overhead. The performance overhead is mostly the same in Java/Kotlin, but the fact that you're using the language to starts with indicates that you can probably make do with that.

Comment: It's not *always* a code smell. This is a good article about the subject: https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails

Comment: Just make sure your list is never empty because you'll get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: You can get into trouble with using `is` on the contents if there is an inheritance hierarchy, though. If you had a `Data<Number>` containing Ints and Doubles, the wrong branch of your `makeCol` function might get selected. This could be prevented by giving the interface a KClass property to enforce its type and allow it to be checked.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The problem I was running into does seem pretty similar to the dilemma described in your link, and it was useful.